# Custom filters for Umbraco Backoffice List View

Tags: umbraco

I have created a document type which uses a List View to show its children. The children are another document type, representing people with addresses, etc.

The List View provides a 'Search' field, however I would like to implement some additional filters, like date ranges, or a drop-down list based on the data in one of the columns.

Is this possible in a standard Umbraco implementation? Thanks!

Comment: Not in a standard Umbraco installation, no :-s

Comment: Thanks Jannik. Just to be clear, I'm happy to implement these filters, just not sure where I can put them. Or do I need to create a whole new admin section rather than extend the List View functions?

Comment: you can create a custom list view layout, follow this tutorial https://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2016/custom-list-view-layouts/